# jQueryUI sortable change position?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am doing something like http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid using jQueryUI Sortable.
However, I was wondering if there is a way to **change the position** of the dragged item and the dropped position instead of sorting them.

For example, in a 3x3 grid below
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

if I drag grid 1 to grid 4, jQuery-sortable by default, would have the new positions as
**4 1 2**
**3** 5 6
7 8 9

However, I would like it to be
**4 2 3**
**1** 5 6
7 8 9

Is there a way to do that by hooking onto some events or via some hack?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should have a look at the [jQuery swapable plugin](http://vadimkir.blogspot.de/2010/08/swappable-jquery-plugin.html). I haven't used it myself, but it seems to do what want.
Look at the [grid demo](http://www.eslinstructor.net/demo/swappable/swappable_grid.html).

Comment: I am also finding this. Thanks. I hope I can edit this code to suit my needs.